# Overwriting/Changing a parameter in Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a procedure like this:

```
PROCEDURE UPDATE_STAT(p_STAT STATS.STATID%TYPE)
IS
 ...   
BEGIN
 ... 
        if (X = 5)
    THEN
        p_Stat := 17;
    END IF;
...
    UPDATE TBL_A SET STATUS = p_Stat WHERE ...
...
END
```

Problem is when I try to compile this I get the error:

```
PLS-00363: Expression 'p_Stat' cannot be used as assignment target.
```

Anyone have a workaround or solution to this? Are local variables the only things that can be used in this way? This parameter is used quite a bit in the body of the function so replacing every instance with a case statement will be a pain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the parameter as an `IN` parameter - that means you can't change it, which if you think about it, makes sense. It's a constant, in effect.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could do this instead:

```
PROCEDURE UPDATE_STAT(p_STAT STATS.STATID%TYPE)
IS
    v_stat stats.statid%type;
 ...   
BEGIN
    v_stat := p_stat;
 ... 
    if (X = 5) THEN
        v_Stat := 17;
    END IF;
...
    UPDATE TBL_A SET STATUS = v_Stat WHERE ...
...
END
```

Comment: I had no idea it worked like a constant. Thanks so much. - will accept in 6 minutes

Comment: You might want to read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS659) about the parameter modes (IN, IN/OUT, OUT).

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can handle this:

#### Use the parameter as a IN OUT parameter

Redeclare your procedure as: `PROCEDURE UPDATE_STAT(p_STAT IN OUT STATS.STATID%TYPE)`. Please be aware that this changes the value of p_stat also in the calling PL/SQL block, so this might have unwanted side effects!

#### Declare a local variable first and assign the procedure parameter to it

```
PROCEDURE UPDATE_STAT(p_STAT STATS.STATID%TYPE)
IS
 l_stat STATS.STATID%TYPE := p_stat;
BEGIN
 ... 
        if (X = 5)
    THEN
        l_Stat := 17;
    END IF;
...
    UPDATE TBL_A SET STATUS = l_Stat WHERE ...
...
END;
/
```

Comment: unwanted side effects?

Comment: that kinda put me off sorry.. ill go with the previous answer as it was the solution i went with.

Comment: Yes, the side effect of an IN OUT parameter is that the value of p_stat will be changed after you called update_stat in the calling PL/SQL block. You can view an IN OUT parameter as a sort of return value of a function (although a procedure might have many OUT parameters and a function can only return one value).